# Python IP address management module

Tags: python, function, loops

I'm a noobie at Python and got this task, which I'm having trouble in starting.

I've an IP.log file with this info:

```
12.0.0.1 120 x
188.1.1.1 12 x
199.1.1.1  3 
99.1.5.5 1
```

Bassically I've to make an app with such functionalities: Sorting the file by IP, deleting records, adding record, markinf /unmarking the IP address, editing the records, reseting the count to zero. The read file should display something like this:

```
  1 | 12.0.0.1    |  120 | x
  2 | 188.1.1.1   |   12 | x
  3 | 199.1.1.1   |    3 |    
  4 | 99.1.5.5    |    1 |
```

Any help to help me get on track would be appreciated.

Comment: What about using `pandas`? use `pandas.read_csv` with `sep= " "`

Comment: BTW: standard module [ipaddress](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ipaddress.html)

Comment: BTW: if you don't use `panda` (but `csv`) then you can use [PTable](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/PTable/0.9.0), [tabulate](https://bitbucket.org/astanin/python-tabulate) to display table.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Python3:

```
s = ['12.0.0.1 120 x', '188.1.1.1 12 x', '199.1.1.1  3', '99.1.5.5 1']
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
  for i, line in enumerate(s, start=1):
      f.write(('{} |'*(1+len(line.split()))).format(*[i, *line.split()])+'\n')
```

Python2:

```
import itertools
s = ['12.0.0.1 120 x', '188.1.1.1 12 x', '199.1.1.1  3', '99.1.5.5 1']
with open('filename.txt', 'a') as f:
   for i, line in enumerate(s, start=1):
      f.write(('{} |'*(1+len(line.split()))).format(*list(itertools.chain(*[[i], line.split()])))+'\n')
```

Output:

```
1 |12.0.0.1 |120 |x |
2 |188.1.1.1 |12 |x |
3 |199.1.1.1 |3 |
4 |99.1.5.5 |1 |
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the module `pandas`. Do the following:

```
import pandas as pd

# Load your data from the file
data = pd.read_csv("path_to_the_file", sep=" ")
                                            ^ space here
```

And you're done!
Have a look at your data if you want:

```
data.head()
```